# Rails, trying to install forked gem from github hangs bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I have found fork of one gem in github, which is more up to date. I wanted to install [this fork](https://github.com/Root-App/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem) to my rails project. So I have added this line of code to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rootapp-wkhtmltopdf-binary', github: 'Root-App/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem'
```

When I run `bundle install`, it just hangs at fetching.

Why does this happen?

Comment: What happens if you use `git` directly instead of `github`? e.g. `git: 'git@github.com:Root-App/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem.git'`

Comment: Running gem install at command line it says there is no valid gem in this repository. Unfortunately the repo has no badge indicating if the gem is building okay or not. Maybe it is just the fact this repo is not building.

Comment: Hm, that's probably the issue. The git repository would have to have the directory structure and format of a proper ruby gem in order for it to work with Bundler.

Comment: It also has gemspec file.

Comment: have you tryed to checkout the git repo manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bundler is not actually hanging, it is downloading the content of the repository in the background.

The repo-content seems to be of a significant size (multiple megabyte). Depending on your connection you will have to wait a while for bundler to finish downloading. Afterwards it should install the gem as usual.

Unfortunately bundler is not giving any feedback on this, even when you invoke bundler in verbose mode `bundle install --verbose`